# What is the word for a person who never listens to other people's opinions and ideas?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

There is one person I know who never accepts other people's opinions and ideas, even if those opinions and ideas are worthwhile. What single word might describe such an attitude?

Comment: What about stubborn?

Comment: Even more derogatory (or familiar) and figurative could be: a mule  :-)

Comment: I think the phrase which captures this with the fewest additional connotations may be *close-minded*.

Comment: *That guy never listens. He is the most stubborn, mulish, close-minded, arrogant, headstrong, adamant, inflexible person I know.*

Comment: Or is it 'closed-minded'?

Comment: #Rupe: You should post *close-minded* as an answer - it is the best given so far, IMO. And yes, *closed-minded* is the same thing.

Comment: Egotist is the right word to use

Comment: My "son"... *sigh*

Comment: @bib - You left out *pig-headed*.

Comment: @HotLicks It would be *pig-headed* of me not to recognize that smithkm got there first.

Answer (score 5):

*[Narrow-minded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narrow-minded#Adjective)* (“having restricted or rigid views, and being unreceptive to new ideas”),  *[small-minded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/small-minded)* (“Selfish, petty; constrained in thought, limited in scope of consideration, not mindful of the big picture”), and  previously-mentioned *[close-minded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close-minded#Adjective)* (“unreceptive to new ideas or information; not open to any agreement”) are all relevant, as are some of their synonyms like *[hidebound](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hidebound)* (“Stubborn; narrow-minded; inflexible”) and previously-mentioned *[pigheaded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pigheaded)* (“Obstinate and stubborn to the point of stupidity”).

Also consider  *[intolerant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intolerant#Adjective)* (“... close-minded about new or different ideas. indisposed to tolerate contrary opinions or beliefs; impatient of dissent or opposition; denying or refusing the right of private opinion or choice in others ...”) and  *[illiberal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/illiberal#Adjective)* (“narrow-minded; bigoted”).

Calling the person *blinkered*, meaning fitted with [blinkers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blinker#Noun), which are  “eye shields attached to a hood for horses, to prevent them from seeing backwards and partially sideways” or *[blindered](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blinder#Noun)* would imply they can only see straight ahead, *ie* only what they are already looking at.

Some terms mentioned in previous ELU questions ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51451),[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43344),[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125926),[4](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32322),[5](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130226),[6](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133063)) are relevant.  Links to wiktionary definitions are shown.
 • *[myopic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myopic#Adjective)*, “narrow minded”
• *[solipsist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solipsist#Noun)*, “One who adheres to self-absorption and an ignorance of the views or needs of others”
• *[self centered](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-centered)*, “Of a person, egotistically obsessed with himself or herself”
• *[uncooperative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncooperative)*, ie not working well with others
• *[ossified](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ossified)*, lit., converted to bone, fig., inflexible and rigid in habits or opinions

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any nouns referring to such a person but the adjective *pigheaded* covers it well and the attitude is *pigheadedness*.  You might use *pighead* to refer to a pigheaded person, but this is not a normal usage and I expect a lot of people wouldn't get it unless you explained what you meant.

> 1. (pejorative) Obstinate and stubborn to the point of stupidity.

source: Wikitionary

Answer (score 2):

I think [headstrong](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/headstrong) conveys the idea: (adj)

> 1. Determined to have one's own way; stubbornly and often recklessly willful. See Synonyms at obstinate, unruly.
> 2. Resulting from willfulness and obstinacy.

Examples:

> - "You're the most headstrong person I've ever met," he said forcefully, and abruptly turned away.
> - His influence was paramount, though he protested against his master's headstrong championship of the Bourbons.

source: www.yourdictionary.com

Answer (score 2):

Adamant - unshakable or insistent especially in maintaining a position or opinion (from MW)

Inflexible - unwilling to change or compromise. (taken from Oed)

Answer (score 2):

If the reason they won't accept other people's opinions or ideas is because they think their own ideas/opinions are more correct/valuable, then they're: [Arrogant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arrogant).

Answer (score 2):

***Know-it-all*** as defined by [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/know-it-all)

> a person who acts as though he or she knows everything and who
>   dismisses the opinions, comments, or suggestions of others.

Sentence (made up):  He's such a know-it-all, but he didn't ground his circuit like I told him to, and boy, did he get a shock!

Answer (score 1):

[Intransigence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intransigent) - refusing to accept any ideas except one's own.

Comment: Hi davey, welcome to the site. You look to have a good answer here. Can you please back it up with a (dictionary) reference&synopsis so it conforms to site policy?

Answer (score -1):

One possible descriptive term is *bigotry*, which the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bigotry) site defines as

> intolerance toward those who hold different opinions from oneself:
>
> *'the difficulties of combating prejudice and bigotry'*

Comment: The question doesn't have to do with _intolerance_, but rather with _stubbornness_. "Bigotry" has social connotations way out of the field of the question.

Comment: Hi, Arsh—and welcome to English Language & Usage. I appreciate that you have included not just a word suggestion but a definition of that word. In addition, however, it's important at EL&U to cite the source of language (like your definition) taken from a reference work. Please add such a citation (with a link, if appropriate) to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I added a link to the source of the quoted definition, since quotations without attribution are not appropriate at EL&U.

Comment: Another definition of **bigot** is *a person who has very strong, unreasonable beliefs or opinions about race, religion or politics and **who will not listen to** or accept the opinions of anyone who disagrees* and that seems to be close to what the OP asked for.  
See  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bigot